# What's the simplest way in Ruby to group an array of arrays by element order?

Tags: ruby

What's the simplest way in Ruby to group an array of arrays by element order? In other words, to get all the 0th elements, then all the 1th elements, etc.

So if you started with this:

```
[[1,2], [:a, :b], [:alpha, :beta]]
```

you'd get this:

```
[[1, :a, :b], [2, :b, :beta]]
```

I can do it with `zip`:

```
arr = [[1,2], [:a, :b], [:alpha, :beta]]
arr[0].zip(arr[1], arr[2])
```

... but I'd like a more general way that would work for any number of inner arrays of any length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-transpose) is what you're after:

```
a = [[1,2], [:a, :b], [:alpha, :beta]]
p a.transpose #=> [[1, :a, :alpha], [2, :b, :beta]]
```

Comment: That is absolutely what I wanted. Thank you. And... **dang**, I love Ruby. I **knew** there would be a nice way. :)